# Angularjs - Unable to apply ng-style to img tag (using ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I'm using Angularjs in order to display some images in the DOM, and apply some style to them (dim the background). It seems I am unable to apply `ng-style` to the `img` tag. What is the reason to that?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vkqzgs8/1/) here.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 postCon" ng-repeat="post in posts">
          <div class="rel">
             <img src="{{post.link}}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" ng-click="test()" ng-style="{'background':'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('+post.link+')','background-size': 'cover'}"> 
          <li class="del">button</li><li class="getLink">get link</li>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.del{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 10;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.getLink{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 10;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.rel{
  position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: please try ng-style into style

Comment: It doesnt work, the "dim" effect is not applied to the image.

Comment: why you didnot use ng-class

Comment: Why do I *have* to use ng-class?

Comment: @undroid Do you want the image to have transparency : 0.5?

Comment: I want to darken the image, the dark cover should have transparency @mJunaidSalaat

Comment: well it turns ng-style was working just fine you had thois css problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 postCon" ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <div class="rel">
        <div class="cover-img">
          <img src="{{post.link}}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" ng-click="test()" style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));background-image: url('{{post.link}}');background-size: cover">
        </div> 
      <li class="del">button</li><li class="getLink">get link</li>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.del{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 10;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.getLink{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 10;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.rel{
  position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cover-img{
   position:relative;
}
.cover-img:before{
   content:'';
   background: rgba(69, 71, 94, 0.53);
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This still doesnt darken the image.

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular. If you use `ng-style` here it would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that how `ng-style` works. You can see example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-style.asp).

Try this:

In html:

```
<img ng-style="yourStyle">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.yourStyle =
{
    'background': 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))',
    'background-size': 'cover'
}
```

Hope this help.